# WiFI adapter not found on Dell Latitude 3340

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers, dell

A new Linux user here! So, two weeks ago I tried to dual-boot Ubuntu 20.10 with Win 10 20H1 on my Latitude 3340 but the wireless wasn't working. I tried reinstalling it to see if it was just a driver issue. But I checked the drivers using Synaptic and it was there (my WiFi driver being iwlwifi). I had also done a live boot and WiFi also wasn't working there! I also tried `sudo lshw -c network` to check. The ethernet was working perfectly while the network was disabled like:

```
*-network DISABLED
```

So, as you can see. And not only that. I also tried Pop_OS live session and WiFi still wasn't working while it was working fine on Win 10. And my laptop doesn't even have a hardware kill switch!
So I wanted to ask what should I do? And what is the problem that needs to be diagnosed?
Awaiting for your answers! Will try to cooperate with you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Can I do it in a live environment?

Comment: Yes, why not?.. If it is a dual boot, disable Fast Startup Feature in Windows first. That can solve the issue completely.

Comment: I actually deleted Ubuntu and formatted the USB Drive! I mean like I gave up for the time being. I still have the ISO. Will format it and reinstall Ubuntu. Will reply soon

Comment: Ummm... Sorry but I'll have to repair the laptop battery. Will repost the question correctly!